# Python Embeddable Zip File Doesn't Include lib/site-packages in sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am attempting to update our Python version from 3.4 to 3.6.  We are embedding Python into a C++ application, so it seemed logical to utilize the new (since Python 3.5) [Windows x86 embeddable zip file](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/).  However, our application is failing to execute because "lib/site-packages" isn't being added to the `sys.path` variable.  I have confirmed that after installing Python 3.6 on my machine, and running from the installed location, the `sys.path` variable contains (relative to the python directory):

```
'...\\python36.zip'
'...\\DLLs'
'...\\lib'
'...'
'...\\lib\\site-packages'
```

However, when I run from the embeddable zip file on the same machine, the `sys.path` variable contains (relative to the python directory):

```
'...\\python36.zip'
'...'
'...\\\n'
```

In both cases, the "lib/site-packages" directory exists within the Python directory.  I also **don't** have a PYTHONPATH environment variable defined.  Does anyone know how to get the embeddable zip file to act the same as the installed version, with respect to how it determines `sys.path`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After extracting the Python embeddable zip file, there is a file called
`python36._pth` in the root directory.  That file contains the following text:

```
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

As the comment indicates, simply uncomment the `import site` statement by
removing the '#' character.  After doing so, the `sys.path` variable contains:

```
'...\\python36.zip'
'...'
'...\\\n'
'...\\lib\\site-packages'
```

This is still different than the installed version, but is exactly what I
needed in my particular case.

**BEGIN EDIT**

I also discovered that you can remove the `python36._pth` file entirely, which
reverts Python to behavior of the non-embeddable version.

Comment: thank you for this, removing the file fixes `sys.path` and Pip as well

Comment: @Jeff G I am wondering if directly deleting .pth file is gonna have some consequence? Why embeddable python puts .pth file into it?

Comment: @BingjieHan I recommend reading [Using Python on Windows, Section 3.9: Finding Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules).  Relevant excerpt: "*To completely override sys.path, create a ._pth file with the same name as the DLL (python37._pth)... When the file exists, all registry and environment variables are ignored, isolated mode is enabled, and site is not imported unless one line in the file specifies `import site`.*"

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers didn't work for us, we had to modify the ._pth file to directly add the site-packages folder to sys.path. We're working with python 3.8 in a windows embeddable python environment.

So our python38._pth file looks like this now

```
python38.zip
.
python38.zip\\site-packages

#Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
import site
```

To be clear, we ran python initially with just 'import site' uncommented, all we saw in sys.path was the python38.zip and python folder paths, no site-packages at all.

So to all who may venture here, try adding the paths you want explicitly if uncommenting the 'import site' line does not work for you.

Also tried the following in our ._pth file

```
python38.zip/site-packages
```

and this also worked on windows, the '/' was correctly substituted for '\' automagically and site-packages was still in sys path and usable

Comment: Based on your post, it appears you are adding classes/modules within the python38.zip/site-packages directory.  This is a slightly different use case than the original question, but may prove helpful for others trying to figure out the syntax for adding paths within the embedded ZIP archive.

Comment: Well, it might appear like that, but after trying to put classes and modules into site-packages (which seems recommended by the readme.txt inside python38.zip\\site-package), it turned out to be a terrible idea... for us anyway.

I believe the best way to put your own packages/modules into a python embeddable, is to put them in the same folder as the python executable. This way they are not inside a zipped archive, which limits you to only py and pic files, .so and .pyd files aren't allowed.

Comment: Your comment made me realize my question/answer didn't adequately explain my directory layout.   I extracted the embeddable ZIP archive, then added a subdirectory "lib/site-packages/" next to python38.zip, which included my custom packages.  Nothing was ever added or removed to/from the python38.zip file.