# Pip not working - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'

Tags: python, module, pip, package, virtualenv

I have installed Python to `C:\Python`.

I have added the following paths to PATH [environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEo1K.png):

- `C:\Python`
- `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`
- `C:\Python\Scripts`

I have installed `get-pip.py` to desktop successfully, returns the following:

```
Collecting pip   Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools   Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f4/385715ccc461885f3cedf57a41ae3c12b5fec3f35cce4c8706b1a112a133/setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel   Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel Successfully
installed pip-10.0.1 setuptools-40.0.0 wheel-0.31.1
```

When trying to install libraries with `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop>pip install gevent`, it returns the following:

```
Could not import runpy module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'
```

Running this also returns the same error `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop>pip`:

```
Could not import runpy module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'
```

I have searched endlessly for this error and none of them have helped me. I have tried searching for the runpy module but could not find it nor its location.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Please format your code examples properly. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Reinstall Python. And next time, use `virtualenv`

Answer (score 6):

Runpy is installed by default with your environment.

If you are using **virtualenv**, deleting and creating another one should fix the problem.

If you are trying to install globally, try to re-install Python and/or checking the PATH in windows environment variables.

Comment: Not using a virtualenv
Ive reinstalled Python several times and the PATH is how it should be
Added image of environment variables

Comment: Have you tried running python with the absolute path? Like C:\Python\Scripts\python.exe ? What happens?

Comment: Do you mean just running the python.exe file? If i do that it will just print out the version

Comment: Why did you install 'get-pip.py' to desktop? Pip is bundled with newer python installations, maybe this is leaving your system in a inconsistent state.

Comment: Yeah, so Python is OK, problem is in Pip IMO, try to run a pip installation with the absolute path in your 'C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe' to see what happens.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.0, do you know where it would be in the Python folder?

Comment: C:\Python\Scripts>pip.exe
Could not import runpy module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'

Comment: If you run 'python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools' it will remove pip installed by get-pip and maybe you can install pip again..

Comment: I tried running that and it returned
C:\Python\python.exe: No module named pip
Do I need to be in a certain directory?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Virtual environment folder under the C: driver User path named as **Envs**. Then search the **virtual** keyword in the search tab and delete all the Python virtual environment packages and folders. Finally, reinstall the Python
Note - Install Python 64bit for the 64bit machine. Hope You will get some idea from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Embedable Python](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable), don't forget to uncomment [`import site`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443254/python-embeddable-zip-file-doesnt-include-lib-site-packages-in-sys-path) in `python*.pth` file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the virtualenv variable already created.
Create a new virtualenv variable.
Try to pip whatever modules required.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I reset my PC, but kept all my files. I reinstalled python 3.7, but couldn't get the virtual environment to run because of the ModuleNotFoundError. My solution was to open File Explorer and navigate to C:/Users/toman/.virtualenvs (replace "toman" with your user name in the path) and delete all the folders (each one of those folders is an individual virtual environment). Please note that .virtualenvs is a hidden folder, so you might have to set File Explorer to show hidden folders.

Once that was done, I opened PowerShell, navigated to my project folder and entered:

```
python -m pipenv install
```

This recreated the virtual environment and installed the contents of my requirements.txt folder.

```
python -m pipenv shell
```

This worked in launching the virtual environment.

```
pip list
```

This verified that all my non standard libraries had been installed in the virtual environment.