# Enable site packages in embeddable Python

Tags: python, sys, pythonpath

I have downloaded one of the "embeddable" Python distributions for Windows from the [Python.org download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). I have realised that, after adding Pip to it, I can install packages, but I cannot import them. After some digging I found out it comes down the the flag `sys.flags.no_site` being enabled by default. This prevents Python from adding the usual `Lib/site-packages` directory to the path, which is where Pip installs things. Note that `site.getsitepackages()` still shows the right paths, it is just that they are not added to `sys.path`.

I get that this is surely because the "embeddable" distribution is supposed to be portable and kind of standalone, but I still would like to be able to use Pip packages installed under its directory. The thing is, the `no_site` flag can usually by disabled when you start the interpreter passing the `-S` switch, but there does not seem to be a way to re-enable when it is already on by default. And as far as I can tell, this is hardcoded somewhere in the distributed files, there is no configuration file or anything like that.

I know there are a number of workarounds I could resort to (adding `site.getsitepackages()` to `sys.path` by myself, installing packages to the Python root directory...), but I was wondering if there is any cleaner way to change this behavior. Otherwise, if you have tips for how to use this "embeddable" Python with external packages effectively that could be helpful too.

EDIT: The same issue happens for user packages, the flag `no_user_site` also becomes enabled by default, although that is not an issue for me since I actually prefer to disable user site packages.

Comment: You could add the directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @yorodm Yes, that's one of the possible workarounds. It's not very convenient, though, this Python will be called from another process, so I would have to lookup the site packages directory from there and add it to `PYTHONPATH` for the context of that process only (and in principle I cannot modify this parent process, I can only "point it" to the Python interpreter I want it to use).

Comment: Don't know if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443956/5588279. If it is, then this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @Sraw That's actually exactly it, thank you for finding that! Never knew about this `pth` files. For reference in case anyone comes across this, there are explained in [the `site` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) and in [Finding modules](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules) from the guide for Python on Windows.