# Ensurepip not available in Python embedable package

Tags: python, pip, ensurepip

I'm trying to install python on my company provided laptop which has blocked download of exe & tar.gz files. So i download embeddable file. But pip/ensurepip is missing in site-package folder of the embeddable file.
System is running Windows Pro 10.
I tried get-pip.py method, but i get SSL connecting error. The firewall is blocking the connection.
Any help on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you contacted your IT support department?

Comment: Yes. They say it’s policy, can’t be changed. I downloaded tar.go files of pip. I unpack it and found setup.py file. When I run this file , I get error saying setup tools is not found.

Answer (score 0):

It is annoying with such restrictive environment for developers. However, if you have access to another windows machine without such restrictions, you can unzip and create an embedded python fold at the same exact path. Then download get-pip.py and run with python.

Chance is that you may find the installed pip doesn't work and pip is not in sys.path. If so, follow the instruction here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443956 to uncomment

```
#import site
```

and run

```
python -m site
```

to confirm that the \lib\site-packages is added to sys.path. You may also want to delete the directory of USER_SITE

```
%AppData%\Python\Python310\site-packages
```

to avoid surprises. That's a useful feature but could create problems for people unaware of their existence in sys.path.

Lastly, you may also find venv is not available with embedded python. Run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and use virtualenv instead. There are also other well-known missing parts but you at least get the most important tools already. Once tested working, copy the site-packages to your restricted laptop at the exact same path and test it out.  :-)